# Is there a workaround for GRASS i.maxlik 'class' being a keyword in Python?

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am running i.maxlik in python - attempting to automate a processing chain.
I use the command:

```
grass.run_command('i.maxlik', group= group, subgroup=subgroup, class='classification', sigfile = sigfile, verbose = True)
```

Infuriatingly, however **'class'** is a python keyword and it doesn't run due to **'invalid syntax'.**

Would you know a way to work around this? I have tried emailing the GRASS developer list but no response.

Regards

Becky

Answer (score 4):

Per http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library#Use_Python_reserved_keyword, add an underscore to the beginning of the argument that is a reserved word. So your command would be:

`grass.run_command('i.maxlik', group= group, subgroup=subgroup, _class='classification', sigfile = sigfile, verbose = True)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a handy Python trick that you can use to unpack a dictionary into keyword args:

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3

args = {"arg1": "Hello", "arg2": "World"}

myfunc(arg3=1234, **args)
```

**Note the ** before the variable args**

You can just put the class keyword into a dictionary:

```
args = {"class": 'classification' }
```

then pass it as extra keyword arguments:

```
grass.run_command('i.maxlik', group= group, subgroup=subgroup, sigfile = sigfile, verbose = True, **args)
```

Note: You can even do it inline:

```
myfunc(arg3=1234, **{"arg1":'Hello', "arg2":"World"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use args and kwargs technique as suggested by Nathan W but I would avoid that unless you need it also for something else.

The preferred syntax is appending and underscore (`class` becomes `class_`):

```
from grass.script import run_command
...
run_command('i.maxlik', ..., class_='classification', ...)
```

This applies to all functions form [start_command](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/libpython/script.html#script.core.start_command) family.

Note that Eric G is right about the underscore at the beginning in case of GRASS GIS 6 but the behavior was changed recently to underscore at the end to follow Python [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) style guide. The underscore at the beginning will be supported for backward compatibility for some time but it will give you a warning similar to the following one:

```
WARNING: To run the module add underscore at the end of the option <class>
         to avoid conflict with Python keywords. Underscore at the
         beginning is depreciated.
```

If you think that underscore at the the end in GRASS GIS 6 would be useful for you, please create a enhancement [ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/) for this backwards compatibility feature request.